# Is pandas automatically adding a row and a columns in the first position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, concatenation

I'm using pandas to merge some csv files (the range of csv files's number is can vary).
When I run the script, it seems that a column and a row are automatically added (as you can see in the picture below).

I use pandas with python 3.7 and run a windows OS based computer. I use Excel to open the csv files.

Here is the code :

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

L_Log= os.listdir('E://PJT/TEST2/')


dfList=[]
for filename in L_Log:
    filename = "E://PJT/TEST2/" + filename
    typefile=type(filename)
    print = typefile
    print(filename)
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,header=None, sep = ';', error_bad_lines=False, encoding="ANSI")
    #df[1:] = [test[1:] for test in df[1:]]
    dfList.append(df)
concatDf=pd.concat(dfList,axis=0)
concatDf.to_csv('Concat2.csv', sep = ';')
```

The result I get is shown in the picture and what is higlighted with excel is what I expect : [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tM8O.jpg)

Thanks for your help !

UPDATE :
I changed the code a little bit : I deleted the part when it add the column's titles and i added a

```py
concatDf.to_csv('Concat2.csv', sep = ';',index=False)
```

Here is the full new script :

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

L_Log= os.listdir('.')

L_LogClean=[]

'''
for k in range(len(L_Log)):
    if 'Logfile_' in L_Log[k]:
        Tempo = L_Log[k]
        Tempo2 = Tempo[12:16]+Tempo[10:12]+Tempo[8:10]
        Tempo2 = int(Tempo2)
        L_LogClean.append(Tempo2)
        L_LogClean = sorted(L_LogClean)

for k in range(len(L_LogClean)):
    Tempo = str(L_LogClean[k])
    Tempo2 = 'Logfile_' + Tempo[6:8]+Tempo[4:6]+Tempo[0:4]+'.csv'
    L_LogClean[k] = Tempo2
    print(L_LogClean)
'''

dfList=[]
colnames=['No.','Date','Time','Temp1','Unit','Temp2','Unit','Lux2','Unit','BP1','Humidité Relat','Unit','CO2','Unit','Présence','Temp1_EnO','Unit','Temp2_EnO','Unit','Temp3_EnO','Unit','RH3_EnO','Unit','Chauffage']
for filename in L_Log:
    filename = "E://PJT/TEST2/" + filename
    typefile=type(filename)
    print = typefile
    print(filename)
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,header=None, sep = ';', error_bad_lines=False, encoding="ANSI")
    #df[1:] = [test[1:] for test in df[1:]]
    dfList.append(df)
concatDf=pd.concat(dfList,axis=0)
#concatDf.columns=colnames
concatDf.to_csv('Concat2.csv', sep = ';',index=False)
```

Now the file seems correct but : It add the name of the columns for each files (and obviously I juste want the first row to show the column's title) 
Here is an exemple of what I get : [What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8ce3.jpg)
Thanks !

Comment: `concatDf.to_csv('Concat2.csv', sep = ';',index=False)`

Comment: It helped me : I have a problem with the column names of each files that are automatically added to the merged file

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set both `index` and `header` to `None`. (Not exactly intuitive in my opinion as it should have been `index` but `columns`, but what can you do.)

To prevent having your column names repeated in the data, you need to set your column names in the csv file as the column names in your dataframe. You'll need to edit the `header` parameter in your for loop where you are reading the csv files with `read_csv`:

```
for filename in L_Log:
    ...
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,header=0, ...)
    ...
```

Comment: My column names are indeed in the data

Comment: Did you try reading your csv files with `header=0` instead of `header=None`? Assuming your column names are the first row of your csv.

Comment: Yes I did it, It doesn't show anymore the header but the columns are mixed alternatively (there is no pattern like the second column is a the third place, the third one at the fourth...) .For instance, instead of having the date at the 2nd colmun, it is at the fourth.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood me. I updated my post to show how to take care of your repeating column names.